# Modern Library - All items View - Image Preview

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, image, json-formatting

Given is a **Modern SharePoint Library with lots of Images**. All Images have additional information in added columns. So the view like "All items" as a list is needed to see added values to every Image.

Would be nice to have a **preview Image of every Image in this library shown in that list-style view**.
In SharePoint 2016 on prem there was a thumbnail column in image libraries.

Is there any JSON to create a preview Image style column? Or is there any other way for modern libraries in SharePoint Online to create a column like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thumbnail Column is missing in Modern Experience document libraries in SharePoint Online. So you cannot select this column in "Edit List View".

**To enable Thumbnail column go to Library Settings - Advanced Library Settings - Enable the first option to be able to add more Content Types - save this with OK.**

**Then in Library Settings add a new Content Type. Select "Picture" and apply with OK.
Now the Thumbnail Column is available to be selected in Edit View. Be patient, it needs a few seconds for the Thumbnails to load.**

Further Information by Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/syedi/need-a-thumbnail-field-in-the-document-library-for-the-uploaded-picture-then-read-this-post

Answer (score 1):

As you are talking about SharePoint Online, per my test image libraries and document libraries both have thumbnail column by default. You can try to edit the view to add this column to your all items view and it will display a thumbnail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is SharePoint Online and it's a regular document library. In "Edit current view" are 35 columns available - but no "Thumbnail". That's why I thought something could have changed in SPO and I would need some JSON to get the thumbnail shown. Will contact MSFT support on this. Will give feedback here on StackExchange.

Comment: @PhilFancy Thanks for your updating. Looking forward to your new findings.